# How to render an App preview in browser using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to show a live preview of an App that updates the view whenever I change something using a form to add/edit the components of this App in the same web page. Similar to what [Siberian CMS](http://www.siberiancms.com/) do. But they use iframe and I saw another method using [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) what I think is better. But I'm pretty new to this tool so I don't have a clue how to acomplish that. There is another way to do this?

Below is an image of Siberian CMS that is very similar to what I need to do:

[image: Example of what I have to do]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing something such as this in React is actually pretty simple.  Your form on the left side would input and share state with the phone on the right side.  I've created a VERY simple example here: http://jsbin.com/jatagoculi/edit?html,css,js,output

Likely the most challenging part would be your layout / css as React makes this very easy.

Essentially, you have your input update `this.setState({key: value})`, and then on the phone display on the right side you would reference the state with:  `<div>{this.state.key}</div>`.  Anytime you type into the input, you would see the change on the phone.

Of course, you can make this much more complicated such as converting arrays (stored in state) to buttons and so on.

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    buttons: [1, 2, 3]
  }
}

var buttons = this.state.buttons.map(item => {
  return <div className="button">{item}</div>;
});

<div>{buttons}</div>
```

You can also have it show and hide components:

```
this.state.showMenu ? this.showMenu : //do something else;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed :) Just one more question if you don't mind.. That app viewed on the phone, needs to be compiled and it will look like exactly the same to that one we see in preview, on the actual phone.  I had an ideia to do this using iframe / Ionic with cordova but now with React I don't know a way. Do you have any ideia? Thanks for your help

Comment: You could certainly use Cordova to package the app and push it to the phone.  To convert the JSX to plain Javascript, I would use Webpack (or Gulp if you prefer that approach).  Then using the normal Cordova CLI which can be found here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html.  Some initial setup is involved... Creating a new project, adding your devices, etc.. but then it is as simple as `cordova build` to create an iOS and Android app.  If you are looking for a way to do this from your website, that may be a bit more sophisticated (see how PhoneGap does it).